# GET byte[] and return using element value?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, uri, arrays

So lately I have been using this method to return a string:

```
string uri = "http://localhost:8000/Service/Student";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
var studentcollection = xDoc.Descendants("Student")
    .Select(n => new
    {
      FirstName = n.Element("FirstName").Value,
    })
    .ToList();
```

And it works fine, but if one of the values from the webservice is a byte[] will this method return that value? If not, how would you combine that method (because im use to it) and return a byte[]?

Comment: Im tempted to say `.Value.ToArray`? would that be wrong

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract a Byte\[\] from an XElement with Linq to Xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319407/extract-a-byte-from-an-xelement-with-linq-to-xml)

Comment: It "could" possibly be a duplicate im not entirely sure, from my webservice I already convert to base64 but I really dont want to convert the byte[], I would like to get it back unconverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that one of the elements could return a `byte[]` or is it really a base 64 encoded string representing a `byte[]`? If the latter, you can extract the bytes from the value:

```
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
```

Full code:

```
string uri = "http://localhost:8000/Service/Student";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
var studentcollection = xDoc.Descendants("Student")
    .Select(Convert.FromBase64String(n.Element("Picture").Value))
    .ToList();
```

Which will give you a list of `byte[]` extracted out of the 'Picture' element for each student (change code accordingly to create Picture as part of your student instance).